# How to add Custom FIeld and save that data into the magento in CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE CREATION & EDIT PAGE

Tags: magento

[image]

I Attached one image so i hope you will get idea what i want to know please help

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you want to create attribute for customer. Its not possible from this interface.Need to do custom coding for it. Or there are some module available in market place please check below module

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-manager-1.html